# Is there a memory-bound Proof Of Work concept for use in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, complexity-theory

I seek a [*Proof Of Work*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) implementable in Javascript. Firstly, I wanted to use some hashcash based approach but realized this might not yield a acceptable protection.
This is because the partial hash reverse task is at best CPU intensive. Here a attacker using a binary to generate this partial reverse hash will very likely beat any Browser performance. (maybe even JIT the enhanced).

Therefore I seek a Proof of Work which is not heavy on CPU but forces a certain number of memory accesses for its completion which I think will be a task in which the Browser's Javascript enines will be much more at pair with a compiled binary solving the same task.I seek a hint how/where to find an implementation of some **memory-bound Proof Of Work** implementations.

Comment: This is one of those questions that the FAQ tells you is not a good question to ask on stackoverflow. We expect you to do your own research, using other means to ask communities for help in searching. Stackoverflow is here to help you find out why code you already wrote is not working, despite being sure it should.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I agree that the question may be imperfect. Indeed I would be happy to develop code for a memory-bound Proof-Of-Work solution in Javascript. But as this is related to security people often caution others to "roll their own thing" and urge to use known things like established ciphers, hashes etc. Also I am sure that the aspect is indeed very much linked to programming and for that can fit on SO. I wonder if enriching the question with a pseudo-code asking for evaluation would make the question better? help!

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of the art in JavaScript-based Proof of Work seems to be [kaPoW](http://kapow.cs.pdx.edu/), for which source is available [here](https://github.com/Steve132/mod_kapow).

The Wikipedia link you provide gives a number of good references for memory-bound Proof of Work, kaPoW should be adaptable to use one of these instead, if you want to use an existing framework.

Comment: At a first glance the **kaPoW** seems to relly also on hash-reversal (at least the source mentions SHA1). I have to find out which methods in the Wikipedia are more in the style of requiring memory-bound feature I was looking to find an answer

Comment: @humanityANDpeace Yes, kaPoW uses hashes. The interesting papers on wikipedia are all referenced on the "Memory-Bound" item in the list of variants, [Coelho's](http://eprint.iacr.org/2005/356) is the most recent there is also [Abadi et al (PDF)](http://www.isoc.org/isoc/conferences/ndss/03/proceedings/papers/2.pdf) and [Dwork et al (large PDF)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/mathusers/naor/PAPERS/mem.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Try my Cuckoo Cycle proof-of-work at https://github.com/tromp/cuckoo

Quoting from the README:

"Cuckoo Cycle represents a breakthrough in three important ways:

1) it performs only one very cheap siphash computation for each random access to memory,

2) (intended) memory usage grows linearly with graph size, which can be set arbitrarily. there may be very limited opportunity to reduce memory usage without undue slowdown.

3) verification of the proof of work is instant, requiring 2 sha256 and 42x2 siphash computations.

Runtime in Cuckoo Cycle is dominated by memory latency (67%)."

Comment: great to see people addressing this issues and application of graph theory etc. Hope I will be able to adopt to Javascript, or is there maybe a javascript implementation already existing that I overlooked?

Comment: No; there's no javascript implementation yet. You'll need to port cuckoo.h and cuckoo_miner.h yourself. But you can leave out some optimizations like the bucketing.

Comment: I wish there was a POW that was *specifically designed* for GPU's ... involving polygon manipulation and/or rasterization operations.   To me that would be ideal.   GPUs are accessible commodity items that would enable such an algorithm to be ASIC resistant.   "Memory hard" algos aren't interesting to me, because ASICs with built in massive DRAM are doable.

Comment: @ErikAronesty You can build ASICs with built in massive DRAM, but then they won't be ridiculously fast. Because "Runtime ... is dominated by memory latency". In fact, we commonly call an ASIC with massive DRAM a CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You could burn bitcoins as a proof of work.   No better evidence of of destroyed value.   Anything you "implement in Javascript" will be cute... but if your chain has any value ultimately someone will build a better one using CUDA, and then Javascript will be useless.